# Formatting tabs HTML PHP CSS

Tags: php, html, css, formatting

I've been away from programming in general for a long time. Amazing how you forget the simplest things. So I'm trying to warm-up my web design/PHP by making a resume generator. 
I made my resume in Word, and I want to try to mimic the document formatting.

I tried doing this with tables, and then I scraped that because it wasn't working exactly like I wanted, and now I'm using divs and spans.

But that's breaking the formatting even more so I don't know what to do...

My main problem is getting spaces to line up precisely the way tabs do in Microsoft Word, on the same line as other things.

Here is the code I'm using

```
function fieldFill($fieldL, $fieldR = 'NoneAtAll'){
$numOfSpaces = 50;
echo '<div class="left">' . $fieldL . '</div>';

//if ($fieldR != 'NoneAtAll'){
//    for($i = 0; $i <= $numOfSpaces - strlen($fieldL); $i++){
//        echo '&nbsp';
//        //echo $i;
if ($fieldR != 'NoneAtAll'){
        for($i = 0; $i <= $numOfSpaces; $i++){
            echo '&nbsp';
        }
    echo '<span class="rightt">' . $fieldR . '</span>';
    echo '<br></br>';
    }
}
```

And here is the CSS section

```
<style>
    .rightt {margin: 0 0 0 300px;}
    .name { font-size: 22pt;}
    .sections {
        padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
    .years {
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*white-space:pre*/
        }
    .jobtits {
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
```

I know there's already good resume generators out there but I'm doing this for the practice. Thanks

Here we go, I want to mimic this format

[image]

As of today I'm finding that this code

```
<div id="page-container">
            <div id="leftside">
                <div class="name">Name</div>
                Address
                <br>
                City
                <br>
                State

                <div class="sections">Objective</div>
                To do good stuff!
                <div class="sections">Education</div>
                A college    
                <div class="sections">Awards</div>
                Did some good stuff
                <div class="sections">Job Experience</div>
                <div class="jobtits">Some place</div>
                Was an editor
                <div class="jobtits">Another place</div>
                Did stuff there too.
                <div class="sections">Skills</div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightside">
                <div class="name">That's my name</div>
                Mobile: 334-223-3244
                <br>
                Home: 334-223-3244
                <br>
                Email: Email@me.com

                <div class="sections">Filler</div>
                Filler
                <div class="sections">Filler</div>
                2012-1030    
                <div class="sections">Filler</div>
                Filler
                <div class="sections">Job Experience</div>
                <div class="jobtits">Jul 00 - 32</div>
                Filler
                <div class="jobtits">Everybody's heard</div>
                About the bird.
                <div class="sections">Skills</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

is working for the most part, but there are still parts that need to overlap, such as the objective line. I probably need to make a new div/table for that huh? I'm walking through the html static before making it dynamic.

Comment: You could always just use `pre` tags. That will preserve tabs and white space.

Comment: But I also want the number of spaces to be interactive, wouldn't pre have to be written in the html?

Answer (score 0):

SPAN tag is inline element so margin will not be appled to it, use DIV tag instead.

Comment: Hi, div breaks off to a next line is the problem. I would like them to be on the same line, but with space between them. I'll put up a sample pic of the type of formatting I'm looking to achieve

Comment: use css floats (float:left) to make sure divs are on same line.

Comment: or use `display: inline-block` on any block-level element.

Comment: Hi I tried floating and while it seems to somewhat fix it, now the text on the right side is aligned via the end letter instead of the beginning. Also I can't figure out how to bring it in a little left instead of being all the way on the right of the page

Comment: You can use a `<table>` for every menu and add a proper **width** to the table.

Comment: Are tables the only way in this sort of thing according to the picture? I remember I started with tables but didn't like them for some reason.

Comment: Ok I don't think this can be done with just one div on the left and one on the right because parts of it, like the Objective, need to be able to overlap with the divs under other words.

Comment: @rbawaskar not true. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878315/span-text-padding-increase-span-size